RuntimeWarning error running MaxEnt in ArcGIS Pro 3.0
I'm encountering this error when trying to run MaxEnt. First time getting to grips with this tool so is stumping me a bit. I've successfully run the tool once with minimum neighbour distance set to 10km, but when trying to run it at 1 or 5km I get the following error. Not sure what it means though as the outputs look fine. I'd like to run at 1km spatial thinning ideally as this matches the resolution of the training rasters (perhaps I don't need to?).
Could someone
translate what the error means & whether I need to do anything?
c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPresenceOnlyPrediction.py:4549: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  predP = NUM.exp(backPred0)
c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPresenceOnlyPrediction.py:4551: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  rawPred = predP / predSum
c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPresenceOnlyPrediction.py:4549: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  predP = NUM.exp(backPred0)
c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPresenceOnlyPrediction.py:4551: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  rawPred = predP / predSum

Failed to execute (PresenceOnlyPrediction).
Failed at 06 August 2024 18:50:23 (Elapsed Time: 1 minutes 29 seconds)

